# iOS / Swift - Limiting access to view controllers to once per day

Tags: ios, swift3

I am fairly new to swift development but i would like to implement limiting access to specified view controllers to once per day, ideally 3am this would reset but 12am is also fine.
How could I implement this?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you visit the view controller, save the current date to user defaults.

Next time the user clicks a button to get to the view controller, read the saved date. If there is no saved date, or the difference between the saved date and the current date is > 24 hours, allow it.

If the difference is < 12 hours, you need to check to see if the date has changed (for midnight) or if 3 am is between those 2 dates.

To see if the 2 saved Dates are on different days, use the Calendar function `isDate(_:inSameDayAs:)`

To see if 3 AM has passed since the last time is more complicated. Off the top of my head, I'd probably take the current Date, `Date()`, and use the function 
`date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of,matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy: direction:)` to create a date for 3 AM today, if it has already passed, and then see if 3AM today is between my saved date and now.